# Bitcoin core verification keeps reseting

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, transaction-verification

I'm trying to run Bitcoin Core service with full node verification on Ubuntu on testnet and it keeps resetting. The verification increases to 0.3, then resets to 0, for 2 days already. Debug.log records look like there was a process crash, but no reason mentioned: 
[image]
The server is Digital Ocean's droplet, I've already tried to increase the server CPU/RAM, no luck. Want to find the reason of what is going on here, what exactly causes such behavior.

Comment: I've seen this before with Raspberry Pi's running out of memory and thus crashing Bitcoin Core. Do you have a way to monitor memory usage? How much memory is available?

Comment: @0xb10c hm.. maybe you're right, I'll recheck that, will set more limit to bitcoin core cache record from config

Comment: @0xb10c you were right: decreasing cache helped! For example you should set somewhere near 6000 for 8GB RAM (I've set 7500 before and it appears that the program was crashing). Can you "Answer" this question, so that I mark the answer for the problem. In the future this can help someone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 0x49D1 reported: reducing the Bitcoin Core database cache helped to reduce memory usage, which caused the crashes while syncing.

In bitcoin.config `dbcache=<n>` or as command-line argument `-dbcache=<n>` where `n` is the database cache size in megabytes (default: 300)

[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)